# Run script only if workbook is open for longer than one second.

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add a counter to a workbook to see how many times the workbook is used. However, the workbook is frequently updated by a script that will open said workbook, add new sheets to said workbook, and close/save the workbook. I would like to only count a use if the workbook is longer than 1/2 a second.

I have tried to add timers to the Workbook_Open function, this is what I currently have tried.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim AlertTime as Double
Application.OnTime AlertTime + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "AccessCounter"
End sub


Sub AccessCounter()
On Error Goto WorkbookAccessedbyMacro:

Counter = Counter + 1


WorkboookAccessedbyMacro:

End Sub
```

With the thought that having the On Error will just do nothing if the workbook is already shut. Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I simply had to move the Sub AccessCounter() to a module. Rookie mistake.